# There is no build compilation issue once a class is removed from a jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am using Eclipse 3.6 IDE for development .

I am working on a Existing Application (The code which was not developed by me ) , this code is present in form of a Jar file ( The class name is ViewOprions )

Inside this code ,  I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException , so for debugging purpose , i removed this class from that jar , built a new jar and added it to the Application .

My Question is that , after removing that class , i was expecting an Compilation problem in the code , but nothing came .

Could anybody please let me know why there is no build problem once a class is removed from a jar ??

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your code isn't using it, and neither are any of the classes from that JAR that you're using.

As Jigar correctly notes below, you may still have an issue when you actually run the code.

I'd advise against fiddling with 3rd party JARs that don't belong to you.  Better to figure out the root cause for the original exception.

Comment: +1 note: It could be using it at runtime so you might expect some exception at runtime

Comment: Yes that class will be called at Runtime only . So if this is the case , doesn't we get the compilation Problems ??

Comment: Don't you believe the compiler?  Why are you asking if you'll get compilation problems when you've compiled successfully?

Answer (score 1):

That class may be accessed through reflection only so the compiler doesn't see any problem. See if you can run your Existing Application. Also, a stacktrace of that IOBE would be helpful in helping you better.